# Can public key be used for decryption (verification) of the document encrypted (signed) using private key

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

In many websites and textbooks they say that public key is always used for encryption and private key is used for decryption.In RSA algorithm ,this is true.But in digital signatures,the sender signs(I believe that this is a somewhat similar to encryption,please correct me if this was wrong)the document using his private key and receiver uses the public key contained in the document to decrypt(verify) it.So,can this be generalized that public /private keys maybe either used for encryption or decryption based on our application?
Or is there some other concept involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital signature and encryption use similar cryptographic operations (not equals) but they have a different purpose:

- **encryption**: hide the data
- **digital signature**: integrity of the data and identity of the signatory

Answering your question, a digital signature operation "signs" the data with the private key. It is not encrypted in any way (the content is not hidden). The public key  is used to verify that the signature corresponds with the original data and the signatory.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. This is how digital signature works. If the answer is too short, let me know, I provide more details.

Comment: I also read another version of digital signature that sends the public key to receiver.Receiver uses this to encrypt the data and sends it back to the sender so that the sender can use his private keys to decrypt it.Which is actually correct?

Comment: Also why am I not finding anywhere that either of them can be used for decryption/encryption.No one says that on the internet.Thats why I was so confused about this.

Comment: Is there any reason why people hesitate to mention that they can be used for both.I mean is there any point at which it can be wrong in some manner.

Comment: @akshay: To *"... that sends the public key to receiver"*: Sender can make its public key available to the receiver or to everyone not only by sending. Sender can publish its public key on its web site, or publish in some repository available to everyone, or use other ways. Yes, when somebody encrypts a message using some one's public key, only the owner of the private key will be able to decrypt it. To *"why people hesitate to mention"*: For many it is obvious: If you encrypt with a private key, you can decrypt with a public key; if you encrypt with a public key, you can decrypt with private.