# Cryptography.py using encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key

Tags: python-3.x, rsa, python-cryptography

I need to encrypt a string using a private key. Then I want to use the asymmetric public key to decrypt the encrypted string and obtain the original string. I am using cryptography.py which allows the opposite (public for encryption and private for decryption). Is there a method included with this library that would allow me to do this?

Note: I have tried to use the private_key.sign() method and this works for encryption. Reading articles I learned this is not a safe nor 'good' way of encrypting and is only used to verify the key.

I am open to using a different library if I need to. I have done a lot of research on this topic and can not find anything online that works with python. Im open for suggestions, thanks.

I will post my code below, read_public() and read_private() is returning an rsa object from crytopgraphy.py

```py
def encrypt(message):
    ######### Public (shared) device only #########
    message = bytes(message,'utf-8')
    private_key = read_private()
    encrypted = private_key.encrypt( #use private
        message,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return encrypted

def decrypt(encrypted):
    #########      Private device only    ##########
    #encrypted = bytes(encrypted, 'utf-8')
    public_key = read_public()
    original_message = public_key.decrypt( #use public
        encrypted,
        padding.OAEP(
            #mask generated function object 
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return original_message
```

output: [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLYje.png)

I understand this error message and why it does not work, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: It very rarely makes sense to "encrypt" with the private key. So perhaps you can explain what you're trying to accomplish and why you think it can be accomplished by encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public key.

Comment: I’m not sufficiently familiar with Python, but is this a duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228645/how-can-i-encrypt-with-a-rsa-private-key-in-python

Comment: @President. Encrypting with your private key enables any receiver (who can decrypt with your public key) to be sure that the message came from you

Comment: Signing is not encryption. Signing is used to verify the _data_ (not the key), but it is not intended to keep anything secret and does not do so; since the purpose of encryption is secrecy, signing is useless for encryption. 'Encrypting with the private key' also doesn't provide secrecy, and is not encryption. What are you trying to do? @racraman: see list at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/#159289

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I am writing an algorithm that encrypts the user message and embeds it in a photo using steganography. This acts as a hidden digital signature to verify the image is authentic. Any user will be able to use the public key to verify their image is authentic: public key know to the world for decryption. Only one person should be able to encrypt: private key secret.

Comment: @racraman I dont think this is a duplicate as the link you referenced is using pycrypto and this is using cryptography. Different libraries

Comment: What you and @racraman are talking about is signing, not encryption. You sign with your private and others verify with your public key. Use the signing API of the cryptography package.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I mentioned signing above. To my understanding signing allows you to verify you are using the correct asymmetric key. The way cryptography implements signing and verifying is the following:

Comment: Comment not allowing me to place code in code format. Verify requires both signature (encrypted message) and original message. So how would one have access to the original message if that is what they are trying to decrypt? I either don't fully understand sign and verify or this method is not going to work for the application .

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk please see this response. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890532